# Unobtrusive JS (MVC3) is causing a delayed DOMContentLoaded event

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, unobtrusive-validation

Despite removing all my code from $.Ready(), it appears that `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` is calling some heafty on load code which is resulting in a 300ms lead-time for our DOMContentLoaded event to fire.

We do have a pretty large DOM, but surely it shouldn't take that long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst tackling some performance dragons on a product I am working on, it appeared that my DOMContentLoaded event was taking 700ms in IE 9 (We have a pretty big DOM - which is also on my list to tackle)

After disabling all my OnReady code - I narrowed it down

`parse(selector)` in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

After finding:

`$(selector).find(":input[data-val=true]").each(function () {...}` I knew immediately the structure of the selector in the Find() method, that this would go into the sizzle engine, and not use the `Document.QuerySelectorAll()`.

--Edit as per comment from @CharlesC--

A minor change of the selector to:

`$(selector).find("input, select, textarea").filter("[data-val=true]")` resulted in a 300ms performance gain within IE.

Comment: There is a significant difference between find("input") and find(":input"). The :input virtual selector. Without the : you are going to miss selects and textareas.